# Best practice for implementing Nested GridView up to 4 levels?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, nested

How do I implement nested gridview up to 4 levels?

```
 + Level 1
   + Level 2A
      + Level 3A
      + Level 3B
          Level 4
   + Level 2B
```

Comment: My immediate thought when reading this question title was "Best practice to shoot yourself in the face...?"

Comment: Will there always be exactly 4 levels or will some have less?

Comment: It may be less but max depth will be 4.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Personally I would question whether a Gridview is the most intuitive way to display such nested data - but if you have no other choice and don't mind paying for a third party component I would recommend at [telerik's RAD Grid](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx) which supports nested tables very seamlessly.

Have a look at [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/hierarchy/nestedviewtemplate/defaultcs.aspx) in particular. [This demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/detailtabledatabind/defaultcs.aspx) also explains the databinding structure.

Comment: We need to do this without need for a third party components.

Comment: I highly recommend using Telerik RadGrid.

Comment: Telerik Rad controls are extremely resource heavy even in light mode. An extra kick in the rear - Rad Controls do not support JQuery, AT ALL.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a bet with a colleague that I could write code using ASP.NET controls to display nested data (using either a Repeater or GridView) far easier than he could write the same code usign XSLT. Unfortunately for me I was wrong and the XSLT option proved far more flexible and scaleable.

So whilst not answering your question I would suggest that you have a look at using XSLT to provide the result. If I can find the code I will update this answer.

Answer (score 0):

With an approach like this, performance will become an issue. Definitely not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same problem and developed my own implementation with Gridviews, Ajax and jQuery. It only loads what is needed when its needed. I wrote [an article over on my blog](http://eugeneniemand.wordpress.com/2010/08/25/dynamic-nested-asp-net-gridview-using-ajax-webservices-and-jquery/) explaining step by step how to implement it and its actually quite simple.